# check if all inputes with same class and textarea if both empty or not

Tags: jquery, html

Hello the problem is that if textarea is not empty..it shows that all fields not empty even if inputes are indeed empty.

**Html**

```
<div  class="h12">
<input class="h12lol" type="text" name="title" placeholder="nom"></input></div><br>
<div class="h12">
<input  class="h12lol" type="text" name="lieu" placeholder="date et lieu de naissance"></input></div><br>
<div class="h12">
<input  class="h12lol" type="text" name="adress" placeholder="adresse"></input></div><br>
<div class="h12">
<input   class="h12lol" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"></input></div><br>
<div class="h12">
<input  class="h12lol" type="text" name="int" placeholder="Telephone"></input></div><br>
<div class="h12">
<input  class="h12lol" type="text" name="page" placeholder="Les pages"></input></div><br>
    <div class="h12">

    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2048000" />

<input  class="h12lol"  style="visibility: hidden;" name="myimage" type='file' multiple accept='image/*' id='logopics' /><br/><br/></div>
<textarea  class="h12lol" id='editor1' name="article" style="margin-top: 30px;"></textarea>  <input  id="step02" class="svx" type="button" name="step" value="step 02">
```

and this is my script to validate inputs and textarea if empty or not. i have made a fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/2emnrkyg/

**Jquery**

```
   <script> 
       $("#step02").click(function() {

  var hasNoValue;
  var hasNoValue2;
  $("input.h12lol").each(function() {

      if (!$(this).val()) {


          hasNoValue = true;

      } else {
          hasNoValue = false;
      }

  });

  if ($.trim($("textarea.h12lol").val()).length < 1) {

      hasNoValue2 = true;

  } else {
      hasNoValue2 = false;
  }
  if ((hasNoValue) && (hasNoValue2)) {
      alert('all empty')

  } else {
      alert('all no empty')
  }
```

});

Comment: u need to validate all fields alone ?

Comment: no i need to check if inputes and the textarea both are empty or not..if both empty i alert all empty..if not i alert both not empty..but the problem is when texarea is not empty  and inputs empty ..it shows that all is empty,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

you need to break the condition once its comes under in foreach condition

[Check out the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2emnrkyg/3/)

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#step02').click(function(){
        var inputvalue = 0;
        $("input.h12lol").each(function() {
        if(inputvalue == 0){
        if($(this).val() == ''){        
           inputvalue = 0;
        } else {
       // alert('not empty');
           inputvalue = 1;
        }
        }

        });

        if($("#editor1").val()== ""){
         var textarada = 0;
        } else {
        var textarada = 1;
        }

        if(textarada == 1 || inputvalue == 1){
            alert('all not empty');
        } else {
        alert('all  empty');
        }

        });
    });
```

Comment: yea glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is if the last one is no empty the hasNoValue will be set to false, even if one of the inputs is empty.

You need to break the if. A quick fix will be:

```
$("input.h12lol").each(function() {
      if(hasNoValue != true){
          if (!$(this).val()) {
              hasNoValue = true;
          } else {
              hasNoValue = false;
          }
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead to cycle with the jQuery.each you may filter all the input elements in order to get only the not empty ones.

```js
$(function () {
  $("#step02").click(function () {
    var hasNoValue = false;
    var inputsNotEmpty = $("input.h12lol").filter(function (index, element) {
      return this.value.trim() != ''
    });
    if ($("textarea.h12lol").val().trim() == '') {
      hasNoValue = true;
    }
    if ((inputsNotEmpty.length == 0) && (!hasNoValue)) {
      alert('all empty')
    } else {
      alert('all no empty')
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="h12">
    <input class="h12lol" type="text" name="title" placeholder="nom">
</div>
<br>
<div class="h12">
    <input class="h12lol" type="text" name="lieu" placeholder="date et lieu de naissance">
</div>
<br>

<div class="h12">
    <input class="h12lol" type="text" name="adress" placeholder="adresse">
</div>
<br>
<div class="h12">
    <input class="h12lol" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
</div>
<br>
<div class="h12">
    <input class="h12lol" type="text" name="int" placeholder="Telephone">
</div>
<br>
<div class="h12">
    <input class="h12lol" type="text" name="page" placeholder="Les pages">
</div>
<br>
<div class="h12">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2048000">
    <input class="h12lol" style="visibility: hidden;" name="myimage" type='file' multiple accept='image/*'
           id='logopics'/><br/><br/>
</div>
<textarea class="h12lol" id='editor1' name="article" style="margin-top: 30px;"></textarea>
<input id="step02" class="svx" type="button" name="step" value="step 02">
```

Comment: when i click on step 2 and put text in textarea and leave inputs empty..it alert "all not empty" but it should alert "all empty" look like the above example